# Debugging logrotate postrotate script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logrotate, debugging

Following is my logrotate conf.

```
/mnt/je/logs/apache/jesites/web/*.log" {
        missingok
        rotate 0
        size 5M
        copytruncate
        notifempty
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                /home/bitnami/.conf/compress-and-upload.sh /mnt/je/logs/apache/jesites/web/ web 
        endscript
}
```

And compress-and-upload.sh script,

```
#!/bin/sh
# Perform Rotated Log File Compression
tar -czPf $1/log.gz $1/*.1

# Fetch the instance id from the instance
EC2_INSTANCE_ID="`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`"
if [ -z $EC2_INSTANCE_ID ]; then
echo "Error: Couldn't fetch Instance ID .. Exiting .."
exit;           
else    
        /usr/local/bin/s3cmd put $1/log.gz s3://xxxx/logs/$(date +%Y)/$(date +%m)/$(date +%d)/$2/$EC2_INSTANCE_ID-$(date +%H:%M:%S)-$2.gz
fi
# Removing Rotated Compressed Log File
rm -f $1/log.gz
```

The files are rotated, but shell script is not executed. I don't know how to debug the postscript.

Is there any logfile I chek to see if there is any permission issues.

If i directly execute the script from commandline file upload works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`logrotate` usually runs as a cron job, and its errors end up being mailed to `root`.  Have a look at `/var/mail/root`, or alternatively make sure that `/etc/aliases` directs `root`'s mail somewhere sensible, and that your instance can in fact send mail.